# .Net WebRequest: Get all vars in querystring of POST/GET-calls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, post

Is there a possibility within the .Net-Framework to retrieve the `Post\Get-Variables` from a Request? Regardless of the HTTP-Requesttype.

i'm aware of the existance of `Request.Querystring`, but that doesn't work in this case (as the data is given with `POST`). I do know about the `ServerVariables-Property` , but subtracting two `Namevaluecollections` just doesn't seem efficient nor proper.

Example (In case of a Post):

```
   Request.QueryString: Counts 0 Keys (Variables are passed using $.Post of Jquery)
   Request.Params: Counts 58 Keys
   Request.ServerVariables: Counts 54 Keys
   Request.Form: Contains the 4 keys needed
```

Example (In case of a Get):

```
   Request.QueryString: Contains the 4 Keys needed
   Request.Params: Counts 58 Keys
   Request.ServerVariables: Counts 54 Keys
   Request.Form: Contains no Keys
```

I'm despratly searching for a method/logic to implement so that in both cases I can get those 4 keys needed (without needing two functions for Get-Post).

So to all you ASP.Net brainiacs, is there a property/method/algoritm that you know of that might just do the trick (Google doesn't seem to like this question or me)?

**Note:** *i don't know how many actual `Post-Parameters` will be posted (Or what the keys might be)*. The method will store the `Post-Parameters` in the database in case of problems/exceptions/errors that might occur during certain transactions (or in other words it will be used for problem solving/debugging).

Thank you gladly for your time

Comment: what is your exact question ? did you want to traverse the `request.form`... what else?

Comment: Edited the question somewhat. If something isn't clear, feel free to point it out.

Comment: please check the answer. Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm despratly searching for a method/logic to implement so that in both cases I can get those 4 keys needed (without needing two functions for Get-Post).

`Request.Params` has got

> Gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables items.

so this will have your required data too.

> Contains the 4 Keys needed

So that you can make use the same.

Example:

Your POST Method:

```
getData()
{
     Request.Form["YourKey"]
}
```

Your GET Method:

```
 getData()
 {
     Request.QueryString["YourKey"]
 }
```

Try this common Method

```
 getData()
 {
      var keys = Request.Params.AllKeys.Except(Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys)
                .Except(Request.Cookies.AllKeys);
 }
```

Check out [Request.Params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Not really what i need. As you might have read, i don't know how many and what keys the request may contain. I just want the Namevaluecollection which i can output for debugging purposes. And i know about Request.Params. yet this will output all the server-variables as well and i'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Sweet! Just what i needed! Thnx!